# Can't able to implement fancybox on magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs-config.js, fancybox

I am trying to add fancybox for Youtube Videos in my store but when I click on the picture, it redirects me to youtube rather than opening a pop-up. I have tried all the solutions available on this forum but nothing worked for me.

**This is my require.js file.**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'fancybox': "js/jquery.fancybox.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'fancybox': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

**This is my .phtml file**

```
<script>
require(['jquery','fancybox'],function($) {
$(window).load(function () {
     /*alert('load from external jquery');*/
});
});
</script>

<a class="btn btn-default2" href="https://youtu.be/7mHaxFcY4QY" data-fancybox>PLAY</a>
```

Here all the frontend code lies. As I said I have tried almost all solutions regarding this error, nothing worked for me.
Since I am a beginner in Magento 2.It would be helpful if you can explain what does require.js file do?

Comment: What is the location of your js lib?

Comment: @SohelRana \app\code\Company\Custom\view\frontend\web\js This is the location of js lib.